# Object property as object

Tags: powershell

Is there a chance to add object as property of system object?
I have something like this:

```
$temp = New-Object System.Object
$temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "type" -Value $serverType.physical
$temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "id" -Value $item.id
$temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "name" -Value $item.name
$temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "mainobject" -Value $myobject
```

When I add $myobject, in the variable $temp.myobject is only string value(I think that name). All other object properties is missing.

Comment: Your code does not add `myobject` property to `$temp`, so it is strange that `$temp.myobject` return anything at all.

Comment: Your code has `$myobject` and `$temp.mainobject`, but you talk about `$temp.myobject`, which doesn't exist in your code.  If I assume you just typed `$temp.myobject` instead of `$temp.mainobject` by mistake here, however, then your code works for me.  I'm not sure what the problem here is.

Comment: What happens when you type $temp.mainobject?

Comment: return string object only (name of object) if object is diskiinfo, get name of disk. if object is virtual machine, get name of virtual machine

Comment: Sorry. I mean $temp.mainobject off course. Still return nothing usable. I thing that there must be another -MemberType (not NoteProperty but All or something else)?

Comment: Hm... when I stored get-childitem into $myobject, everything works fine. Problem must be somewhere else. I must check my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this something like what you're seeing?

```
PS C:\> $MainObject = New-Object -TypeName System.Object;
PS C:\> $MainObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Column1" -Value 1;
PS C:\> $MainObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Column2" -Value "2";
PS C:\> $MainObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Column3" -Value 3.0;
PS C:\> $MainObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Column4" -Value ([Math]::Sqrt(16));
PS C:\> $MainObject | Format-Table -AutoSize;

Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
------- ------- ------- -------
      1 2           3.0       4

PS C:\> $SubObject = New-Object -TypeName System.Object;
PS C:\> $SubObject  | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SubColumn1" -Value 1;
PS C:\> $SubObject  | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SubColumn2" -Value @(2,22);
PS C:\> $SubObject | Format-Table -AutoSize;

SubColumn1 SubColumn2
---------- ----------
         1 {2, 22}    

PS C:\> $MainObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Column5" -Value $SubObject;
PS C:\> $MainObject | Format-Table -AutoSize;

Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5      
------- ------- ------- ------- -------      
      1 2           3.0       4 System.Object
```

And you're wondering why you see `System.Object` there?  It's a placeholder.  You're making an object that too complicated for PowerShell's simple tables to display.  There isn't really a good workaround for displaying objects inside objects.  If it's just an array, often it'll work just fine, but sometimes it just won't.  It's a limitation you've got to work around.

You can try to do something like this:

```
$MainObject | Select-Object Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, @{n="Column5";e={ ("<{0}>,<{1}>" -f $_.Column5.SubColumn1, $_.Column5.SubColumn2); }} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

But if you've got complex objects in there it won't turn out well:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5              
------- ------- ------- ------- -------              
      1 2           3.0       4 <1>,<System.Object[]>
```

The objects still work just fine:

```
PS C:\> $MainObject.Column5.SubColumn2[1]
22
```

But they won't automatically display nicely for you.